# Hibernate/Dropwizard: Find or create with @UnitOfWork does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, transactions, dropwizard

We have a rest API that we wrote with dropwizard. One functionality of the API is to create event triples of the form: userID - action - itemID
If there is no action yet for this userID/itemID combination we create a new event. The corresponding resource function has the @UnitOfWork annotation:

```
@POST
@UnitOfWork
@Timed
public Event createEvent(Event event) {
    return eventDAO.updateOrCreate(event);
}
```

If this is the first event for this particular userID or itemID we create a user or an item respectively. This is the function for the items (users is the same):

```
public Item getOrCreate(Event event) {
    Item item = findOne(event.getItemId());
    if(item == null) {
        item = new Item();
        item.setItemId(event.getItemId());
        create(item);
    }
    return item;
}
```

The problem is that we have duplicate items (i.e. errors if we enforce the itemId to be unique). If we have two requests in separate threads like this

```
user1 action1 item1
user2 action2 item1
```

it seems that both try to create one. From the [documentation](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/hibernate.html#transactional-resource-methods) of the @UnitOfWork we assumed that everything would be wrapped in a transaction and therefore this shouldn't happen. 
When we added a database constraint that the itemId should be unique, we get a PSQL exception "duplicate key value violates unique constraint...".

What am I missing?

Comment: By looking at @UnitOfWork code, you can see for each request it is creating new session and the transaction is bound to that session. So it would not work in your case.

Comment: But why not? Isn't having everything in one transaction and one transaction per session exactly what I want?

Comment: Because when you have 2 requests concurrently, you are not in one session, the @UnitOfWork will create you two separate sessions. So one transaction happens in one session while another transaction happens in another session.

Answer (score 0):

A transaction bounding the HTTP request won't prevent the problem you're describing. You've not given the database any indication of what it should use to prevent the double insertion. Unless there's a database constraint indicating that event IDs ought to be unique, the database can't tell that it's the same entity being created in separate requests.

I assume from the description you're giving that you don't have such a constraint on the database. If that's the case, add one and then see what happens. If that's not the case, you may want to update your post with the schema being used for the events table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added the info about the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

A transaction does not automatically lock the row, which is required to block the other thread/request.  You need to use [`LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/LockMode.html#PESSIMISTIC_WRITE), or similar, to accomplish this.